# aws s3 to s3 copy using python script on EC2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am planning to run scripts to copy S3 files from one bucket to other bucket in same region( same account and different account - both cases are there). I am using Python scripts and running on EC2 instance. 
1) Will the performance depend on EC2 server type?
2) What is the best way to improve performance when copying S3 files from one account to another ( and also one bucket to another in same account, same region) . Given they are in same region and different regions. File sizes are around 1 GB each with total size of 5TB

Thanks
tom

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in this instance the type of EC2 will not matter because you are using the AWS network to transfer data from 1 bucket to another. If you wanted to spin off parallel processing of the data (Run multiple s3 cp at the same time) then you would choose a specific instance, but in your case a T2 Small would do just fine.

Comment: Thank you about that. So what you are saying is purely dependent on S3 to S3 and depends on region and account. Just for curiosity what happens if I create thread processes and run 30-50 cp processes in parallel using python code. How i s it going to effect. I will not do it though. Just curious.

Comment: Well if you were to spin up a thread per you would see an issue for example you have 4 CPU sockets, each CPU can have, up to, 12 cores and each core can have two threads. So, your max thread count is, 4 CPU x 12 cores x 2 threads per core, so 12 x 4 x 2 is 96. Therefore the max thread count is 96 and max core count is 48 and you can perform that math depending on what EC2 type you select to determine your thread count possible.

Comment: If I've helped you solve your issue, do you mind marking this as the correct answer? I would appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: I thought u said it doesn't depend on EC2 and only depends on S3 ? I am confused now.

Comment: It's only by S3, I thought you wanted to spin up multiple threads on a CPU. Disregard my other comment.